# Ellipsis or substitution?

Tags: ellipses, single-word-requests

> If they want to get revenge, Abra, I don't mind.
>
> But perhaps **they don't**.

**They don't** in that utterance is included in the verbal substitution *do* or ellipsis? Is the full form

> They don't want to get revenge

Comment: Are you asking what shortening 'But perhaps they don't want to get revenge.' to 'But perhaps they don't.' is called?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes. is it verbal substitution or ellipsis? because there is 'not' there, I can't decide

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think what OP's thinking about, is that there's a pro-verb *DO* and an auxiliary verb *DO*. The former is involved substitutions, the second in ellipsis. This is the auxiliary, but it's not immediately obvious why (although it would be for you or me, I reckon).

Comment: That's just a really odd exchange all 'round.  If the intended meaning is "But perhaps they don't want to get revenge" it'd be much better shortened to, "But they might not [want to][get revenge]"  The use of *but* and *don't* really parallels the "I don't mind" but semantically it's nonsense.

Comment: @Jim The stress on **they don't** licenses OP's version, in my opinion (though I did separate the sentences into mini-paragraphs to distance the parallel _dont_ 's). But this is just asking for a better example rather than offering advice on OP's question.

Comment: This isn't active verb substitution _do_ (_I asked him to pass the salt, and he did_); this is _do_-support _do_. The original is _But perhaps they `Not` want to get revenge_; the `Not` requires _do_-support for _not_: _But perhaps they do not want to get revenge_; _do not_ contracts to _don't_: _But perhaps they don't (want to get revenge)_; and finally, Conjunction Reduction deletes material identical with the first clause: _But perhaps they don't._ "Ellipsis" just means 'something is missing somewhere'; it's not a specific enough term for grammar. Context and conditions are important.

Comment: ... It's late, but I'll try to paraphrase: This is not (active) verb substitution _do_, but anybody asking you to choose between  '(active) verb substitution _do_' and 'ellipsis' here shouldn't be using the imprecise term 'ellipsis'.

Comment: Does it mean it neither substitution nor ellipsis?

Comment: Can the poster rephrase the question?   I don't kniw what's being asked here.

Comment: I got confused to decide whether "they don't" in text contained substitution or ellipsis

Comment: @WillBriggs done

Comment: The full form is as you say:  They don't want to get revenge.

Comment: @WillBriggs is it a substitution or ellipsis?

Comment: My answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(linguistics)#Ellipsis), what you have is ellipsis:  "words are omitted when the phrase needs to be repeated."  The omitted words are "want to get revenge."

Substitution happens when a word is substituted for another word or words.  That's not happening here.  It would if your second sentence were "But perhaps they don't want that."  In such a case, "that" would substitute for "to get revenge."